# Is there a way to use categorical pca in python?

Tags: python, statistics, pca, categorical-data

I need to construct an index that includes several categorical variables from a survey. To calculate weights for each variable I want to use a statistical method such as PCA. PCA is supposed to performed on continious data, however, there is a modification of PCA for categorical variables - CatPCA. Is there any package to perfrom it in python?

Or alternitively, if there is none, is there any other way to construct an index out of categorical variables?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Afterwards I decided to use factor analysis instead, as it works just fine with categorical data, especially with ordinal variables, that [can be considered continuous if specific requirement is met](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/feduc.2020.589965/full).
The method of deploying it in python that I used can be found [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/the-factor-analysis-for-constructing-a-composite-index-2496686fc54c)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).